# Buying certified Canadian checks or money orders online from the US?

Tags: canada, check, money-order

I live in the US and I need to send an application to a consulate in Canada. The consulate only accepts certified checks or money orders issued by Canadian institutions in Canadian dollars and  cannot accept anything issued by a US institution.

Is there a way to order money orders or certified checks online and have them delivered to me in paper form so I can attach one to my application?

Comment: Would Canadian banks that operate in the US count?  E.g. TD Bank.

Comment: Which country's consulate is this?  Canada doesn't have consulates in Canada, and the requirements certainly don't sound American.

Comment: Yes not an American consulate. It's for a country under US sanctions. The said country does not have a consulate or embassy in the US hence we have to send it to canada